# How do I prove this algorithm's correctness?

Tags: algorithm, dijkstra, induction, loop-invariant, proof-of-correctness

**My algorithm:**
Construct a new graph G' whereas for every vertex v in V, create two vertices v_0 and v_1 in G', and for every edge (u, v) in E, create two edges (u_0 , v_1) and (u_1,v_0) in G'. Run Dijkstra on G' starting at s_0.

All paths in G' ending at v_0 have an even number of edges so the shortest even-length path to vertex t in G can be found by determining the shortest path from s_0 to t_0 in G'.

How can I prove the correctness of this algorithm?

Comment: If you set the new edges as `(u_0 , v_1)` and `(u_1,v_0)`, isn't the new graph just 2 disconnected graphs which are both equivalent to the original graph?

Comment: @AbhayAravinda, take for example a triangle (3 nodes, 3 edges). This algorithm would create a graph with 6 nodes, and it would not be disconnected: every node can be reached from every other of the 6 nodes.

Comment: Ah..ok. You were looking at paths ending at t_0. I somehow missed that. Sorry

Answer (score 1):

> All paths in G' ending at `v_0` have an even number of edges

That's not entirely true. `v_0` has some incoming edge, say `p_1 -> v_0`, and that path has odd number of edges (`1`).

But you're close to the truth, though. If we take the original graph `G` and for each vertex `v` we create two vertices `v_0` and `v_1` in `G'`, then we can split `G'` in two (disjoint) sets of vertices - `0`-vertices and `1`-vertices.

And I state that:

> All paths in `G'` that start from any `0`-vertex and end at any `0`-vertex have even number of edges.

This is true, because `G'` is **bipartite**. By definition, a bipartite graph is a graph whose vertices can be divided into two disjoint sets (in our case `0`-vertices and `1`-vertices) so that every edge connects two vertices from different sets. The way we built `G'` makes it bipartite, because we never connect vertices that belong to the same set (we always connect `u_0` with `v_1` and vice-versa)

In a bipartite graph, like `G'`, every path that starts from a vertex from one of the sets and ending at a vertex in the same set, has even number of edges. The only thing left to do is to find out the shortest one (with a shortest path algorithm of your choice).

Answer (score 0):

Assuming start node is S and finish node is F

---

On the modified graph, if we travel from u<sub>i</sub> to v<sub>j</sub> via an edge connecting the two nodes, then `j=(i+1) mod 2` by the way edges are defined.

So if we travel from u<sub>i</sub> to v<sub>j</sub> via any arbitrary path, `j=(i+n) mod 2` where n is length of the path. (conclusion 1)

---

So if we travel from S<sub>0</sub> to F<sub>0</sub> via some path, `0 = (0 + n) mod 2` meaning n is even

So this proves that any path from S<sub>0</sub> to F<sub>0</sub> traverses even edges (conclusion 2)

---

Also, based on how edges are defined in the new graph, we can say that for any edge (u,v) in old graph, edge (u<sub>i</sub>,v<sub>j</sub>) exists in new graph for some i,j (conclusion 3)

---

Now, if in the original graph, an even length path exists, let the shortest path be
SA<sup>1</sup>A<sup>2</sup>...A<sup>2m-1</sup>F  where A<sup>i</sup> could be repeated. (Even edges imply odd number of nodes). Then in the new graph, We can start on S<sub>0</sub> and traverse S<sub>0</sub>A<sup>1</sup><sub>i</sub>A<sup>2</sup><sub>j</sub>...A<sup>2m-1</sup><sub>k</sub>F<sub>m</sub> to land on F (from conclusion 3). Then the subscript on F will be
`(0 + 2m-1 +1) mod 2 = 0` (from conclusion 2). Hence, a path will exist on the new graph too containing the same length.

Hence, if the solution exists, then there exists a path from S<sub>0</sub> to F<sub>0</sub> in the new graph too (conclusion 4)

---

Also, based on how edges are defined in the new graph, for every edge from u<sub>i</sub> to v<sub>j</sub>, then there is an edge from u to v in the original graph. Hence, for any path in the new graph from u<sub>i</sub> to v<sub>j</sub>, there is a corresponding path from u to v in the old graph having the same length

Therefore if a path exists from S<sub>0</sub> to F<sub>0</sub>, there exists a corresponding path in the original graph having the same length (conclusion 5)

---

Conclusions 2,4 and 5 together prove that the shortest path from S<sub>0</sub> to F<sub>0</sub> is the correct answer. If the path cannot be found, then it does not exist in the original graph either (from conclusion 4)

Hence, the algorithm is correct